# Как открыть QT Designer Python на Linux Mint

Tags: python, pyqt5, linux-mint, qt-designer

Требуется работать с PyQt5 и Desiner`ом для него. У меня ОС.Linux Mint. Скажите где валяется файлик с QT Designer и как мне его открыть. Если есть нюансы, расскажите о них пожалуйста

Comment: почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714304/wheres-qt-designer-on-linux-installation-of-pyside2-qt-for-python может поможет.